# Rotation of angle $2k\pi/p$ generates the group of all rotation

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, prime-numbers, transformation, geometric-transformation

In the book [Geometric Transformation of Razvan Gelca](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/3030978486), there is an argument as follows:
[image]

I could understand most of the proof there, however is there any easier explanation for the yellow painted part, i.e: because p is prime then the rotation $2k\pi/p$ generates the group of all rotation of $A_1A_2\cdots A_p$?

As far as I understand there are 2 conditions: $p$ is prime and $A_1A_2\cdots A_p$ is fixed under the rotation $2k\pi/p$. Now the group generated by the rotation $2k\pi/p$ (A) is a cyclic group of order $p$. So my question is:

1- Why it equals to the whole group of all possible rotations (S) if $p$ is prime?

2- So if $p$ is not a prime then $A$ is a proper subset of $S$?  Are there any other special properties?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Nothing more to say, need the 15 character minimum

Comment: I've updated my question.

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 1):

Since $p$ is prime, the group has no non-trivial subgroups. If it did then for some $k$, not all "rotated-permutations" are going to be eventually traversed.

$k$ can be considered the winding number which incidentally is equal to the number of vertices skipped in a rotation by $\frac{2k\pi}{p}$

For illustration see the following figure of polygons and Schläfli symbol $\{n/k\}$ (*created by 'Cmglee' for Wikipedia under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en)*)

[image: Regular convex and star polygons with 3 to 12 vertices labelled with their Schläfli symbols]

Comment: Since there are 2 groups (A & S) here, could you please explain in more detail that which one has no non-trivial subgroups? As I understand, the group generated by the rotation $2k\pi/p$  (A) has order $p$ and has no non-trivial subgroups, but the rotation group that fixed $A_1A_2\cdots A_p$ (S) may be has larger order. I mean $A\subseteq S$ but why $S\subseteq A$ if $p$ is a prime?

Comment: By all rotations I think they mean $C_p$ and they say the group of rotations generated by a $\frac{2k\pi}{p}$ that fixes $A_1A_2\cdots A_p$ given prime $p$ is equivalent to $C_p$. It certainly doesn't produce $\mathbb S^1$

Comment: Can you give a counterexample for the case $p$ is not a prime then the rotation $2k\pi/p$ doesn't generate the whole group?

Comment: Consider star of David